# Truncated Mean in Redshift

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

How should I calculate a [Truncated Mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_mean) in a redshift database? I want it run on very large data sets

Answer (score 0):

Redshift includes the usual SQL statistical functions, including `NTILE` which you'll need for this.

```
SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN quartile IN (2,3) THEN my_metric ELSE NULL END) central_mean
      ,AVG(my_metric) mean
FROM (SELECT my_metric, NTILE(4) OVER (ORDER BY cpu_usage) quartile
        FROM (SELECT * FROM my_table LIMIT 1000 ) t ) t
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the threshold values for the percentiles that you would like to trim out from your set. Then filter the metric values falling outside of the boundaries of these thresholds out and finally you can calculate the average.

```
SELECT avg(your_metric)
FROM (
   SELECT
     your_metric,
     PERCENTILE_DISC(0.1) -- 10% lower boundary 
     WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY your_metric) OVER () AS lower_threshold,
     PERCENTILE_DISC(0.9) -- 90% higher boundary
     WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY your_metric) OVER () AS higher_threshold
   FROM your_table

 ) t1 WHERE your_metric > lower_threshold AND your_metric < higher_threshold
```